# How to sum multiple Product Prices for a unique order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with ordered items where occasionally I have one order ID with multiple lines (1 line for each ordered item).

```
OrderID | Order.Item_id | Item.Price | Quantity | OrderTotal | Seller ID |
1       | 1             | 10         | 1        | 10         |1          |
2       | 2             | 15         | 1        | 25         |1          |
2       | 3             | 10         | 1        | 25         |2          |
3       | 4             | 15         | 1        | 44         |1          |
3       | 5             | 10         | 1        | 44         |1          |
3       | 6             | 19         | 1        | 44         |2          |
```

I need a way to export/display the OrderTotal ONLY for the given Seller ID.

Ideally I need a result in the lines of:

```
OrderID | Order.Item_id | Item.Price | Quantity | OrderTotal | Seller ID |
1       | 1             | 10         | 1        | 10         |1          |
2       | 2             | 15         | 1        | 15         |1          |
3       | 4             | 15         | 1        | 25         |1          |
3       | 5             | 10         | 1        | 25         |1          |
```

In the case of OrderID 2 I can easily pick simply the Item Price but this won't work for OrderID 3 where I need to sum two items. Is this possible using only SQL. Could you please help me?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you add your expected output in question it will be easy for others to provide you solution

Comment: The second table should've been the looked for result. Thanks for the comment, I've tried to make it a bit more clear with spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the sum of orders by order and seller, then join back to order info get the other values:

```
select o.order_id, o.item_id, o.price, o.quantity, q.total, o.seller_id from (
  select order_id, seller_id, sum(price) total
  from   orders
  where seller_id = 1
  group by order_id, seller_id
) q
join orders o on (o.order_id = q.order_id and q.seller_id = o.seller_id);
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3399f/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It is a bit more complicated with a lot of different tables but this definitely get's the gears moving. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try as below

```
Select SellerID,
       OrderID,
       -- below will display the items id comma seperated
       group_concat(Itme_id) as itemlist,
       -- below will display the item price comma seperated, you can use sum(Price) also
       group_concat(Price) as pricelist,
       sum(quantity) as totalquantity,
       sum(OrderTotal) as totalorders
From Table
where SellerID = 1
group by SellerID,OrderID
```